# enntity frame work core two seperate data list from databse entity

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

i have two list in my controller( .net core mvc 2.0, data base access using entity frame work core )

```
homeData.ListBrands = await _context.Brands.Where(b => formdata.UserCategories.Any(y => b.CategoryBrands.Any(c => c.CategoryID == y.CategoryID))).ToListAsync();
homeData.NewBrands = await _context.Brands.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

both are list of brands from data base 
in brand i have colum Logo which contain logo name only to create full path for client i append path with data

```
 homeData.NewBrands.ForEach(x => x.BrandLogo = BrandLogo + "/" + x.BrandLogo);
 homeData.ListBrands.ForEach(x => x.BrandLogo = BrandLogo + "/" + x.BrandLogo);
```

if same brand comes in both list then append url will repeat since they represent same obect.

```
http://localhost:4399/Uploads/BrandLogo/http://localhost:4399/Uploads/BrandLogo/IMKbershkaD_19_Mar_2018_13_10_10.png
```

i have tried with new inside select

```
  homeData.NewBrands=_context.Brands.OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate).Select(x=>new Brand() {BrandCoverImages=x.BrandCoverImages,BrandDEscriptionAr=x.BrandDEscriptionAr,BrandDEscriptionEn=x.BrandDEscriptionEn,BrandID=x.BrandID,BrandLocations=x.BrandLocations,BrandLogo=x.BrandLogo }).Take(5).ToListAsync();
```

it works for me but i have to use new for even inner objects like brandCover images since i have to make changes the path in inner objects also . Is there any other way to create new object while selecting from data base . I am using entity core 2.0  for data access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the [No-Tracking Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#no-tracking-queries). No tracking means that EF (1) won't keep track of the returned entity instances in the context and (2) won't reuse the entity instances already tracked by the context. For more details, see [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/overview).

With that being said, simply add `AsNoTracking()` to the query root:

```
homeData.ListBrands = await _context.Brands.AsNoTracking().Where(...
homeData.NewBrands = await _context.Brands.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(...
```